# I broke my gitlab by -R'ing all permissions on some folders

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, gitlab

I recently had some major brain lag and did `chown -r www-data /var/`.
In /var/, there was a symlink to /run/ as well, which broke my entire server apparently.
I got most stuff back running now, but gitlab is still broken.
I tried to assign the entire /var/opt/gitlab/ folder to the git user, which did not have any effect.

Now I wanted to ask if someone who is running gitlab could tell me the `ll` output of his gitlab folder or tell me what permissions I need to change back.
Also, how can I start gitlab manually? Do I even have to start it, or just nginx? I need to test if my changes work but I don't even how I'd do that.

I'd really appreciate any help given.